# What is use of these gradle terms for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have seen these terms in android gradle files and its quite confusing i have seen these terminologies while creating instant app. Can someone explain usage of these terms:

1. `api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"`
2. `feature project(':main')`
3. `application project(':installed')`
4. `implementation project(":base")`
5. `compile project(":base")`

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that all listed terms appear in a `dependencies` block. Like the name indicates, the project *dependencies* are defined in this block.

The block provides a method for each registered *configuration*. These methods are the first part of the listed terms (`api`, `feature` ...). As example, you could write the first term as:

```
api("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib")
```

Groovy, where Gradle is based upon, allows omitting unnecessary brackets.

The different configurations must either be defined in the `configurations` block or by a Gradle plugin. The `compile` configuration is defined by the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html), `api` and `implementation` by the [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html). Personally, I do not know plugins, that define a `feature` or `application` configuration. Different configurations can be resolved for different uses, as an example, here is the difference between `api` and `implementation`:

> The `api` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the `implementation` configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

The second part of your terms are the dependency definitions, as defined [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies). The first term defines a dependency on an external module (in a Maven repository), all other terms define a dependency on an other Gradle project in a multi-project build.

There is also a special Groovy feature in your first term. Groovy distinguishes between a regular `String` (defined via `'my string'`) and a `GString` (defined via `"my string"`). GStrings allow you to use and evaluate Groovy expressions inside a String via `"my string with $expression"`. In this term, `rootProject.supportLib` is evaluated to define the version of the external module dependency. As an alternative, you could use the map notation instead of the string notation for the dependency:

```
api group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: rootProject.supportLib
```